# How do I add custom icon using inline css on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, icons, font-awesome

I want to add a glassdoor icon. You can find my site at braunweiss.net. My theme uses fontawesome and it currently doesn't support a glassdoor icon. So I tried adding an image in place using the below code:

.social-menu li a[href*="glassdoor.com"]::before {content:url(http://braunweiss.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/glassdoor-2-1.png);}

However, it looks bad, it's not customizable, and it doesn't change when it is hovered like a font. I've read of using svg in inline css but cannot figure out how to do it. Here's where I got the glassdoor icon I used: https://materialdesignicons.com/ (scroll down, the icons are in alphabetical order).

Is there a better way to get the icon to show up? I can only customize css or add codes to my theme's php files on wordpress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an SVG? 
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/6422 (SVG LINK IS IN HERE)

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ Icon SVG how-to.